# How to load .zip files into BigQuery?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

We are able to load uncompressed CSV files and gzipped files completely fine.
However, if we want to load CSV files compressed in ".zip" - what is the best approach to move ahead?
Will we need to manually convert the zip to gz or BigQuery has added some support to handle this?

Thanks

Comment: It might be useful to know that you can decompress files to another GSC location using Dataflow template "Bulk Decompress Cloud Storage Files"
https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/templates/provided-templates#bulk-decompress-cloud-storage-files

Answer (score 4, accepted):

BigQuery supports loading gzip files

The limitation is - If you use gzip compression BigQuery cannot read the data in parallel. Loading compressed CSV data into BigQuery is slower than loading uncompressed data.

Comment: Note that gzip is very different to zip though. If the OP has zip files to start with, the ability to handle gzip won't help.

Comment: Correct! But these are third party files that we receive and can be in higher double digits in terms of compressed GB size, thus loading a compressed file directly. Since we have a lot of zip files coming in now, was wondering if we could use zip files directly similar to gz by specifying an argument for file type. however, it seems to be not available as per your comments above. So, we might switch to other method. Thanks.

Comment: I meant to emphasize that only supported compression for csv is gzip - so you need to take care of unzipping by yourself :o( - you can also submit feature request to bq tracker

Comment: Cool. Submitted the feature request: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/115478928

Answer (score 1):

You can try 42Layers.io for this. We use it to import ziped CSV files directly from FTP into BQ, and then set it on a schedule to do it every day. They also let you do field mapping to your existing tables within BQ. Pretty neat.